# How to generate unique id for each record spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a huge datasets with MM+ records and I am trying to assign unique id to each record. I tried below code but it takes lot of time as row id is sequential. I have tried tweak memory parameters to optimize job, couldn't gain much performance.

**sample snippet:**

```
JavaRDD<String> rawRdd=......
rawRdd.zipWithIndex()
.mapToPair(t->new Tuple2<Long,String>(t._2,t._1))
```

Are there any better way to assign unique id? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:** if you requirement is just to assign unique id, you may use UUID as unique row id:

```
rawRdd.mapToPair(t->new Tuple2<String,String>(t,UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
```

Only drawback is that the id length is 36 bytes.

**Approach 2:** Create a centralize system to assign unique id. I use REST based API which follow a pattern to generate id and each map operation calls REST service to get unique id.

2nd approach gives you full control to design the pattern for id.

Comment: Thanks can you please add more details about approach 2?

Comment: Follow [rest example]( https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/ ) to create centralize id using REST and call it from spark to assign id to each record.