# Generating unique ID for incremental update of Existing RDD in spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd, transformation

I am attempting to do an incremental update to my RDD using **union** in spark. For that I have RDD1 ( already existing).

RDD1 :

```
JavaPairRDD<String,String>(uniqueID,data)
```

where first String corresponds to "UniqueID" and second String is data.

**RDD1 data :**

1000000000006873 | a,b,c,d

1000000000009843 | e,f,g

1000000000005823 | h,g,j

1000000000001870 | z,k

In my incremental process RDD2 is generated.

RDD2 :

```
JavaRDD<String>(data)
```

Here String corresponds to data.

**RDD2 data :**

x,y

s,c,f

q,r,t,z,l

I am trying to convert RDD2 to JavaPairRDD , where first String corresponds to "uniqueId". So that i can eventually union this newly generated RDD2 to RDD1.

For this I am able to convert RDD2 to pairRDD, but how to make sure that uniqueID that i generated for each row of RDD2 , does not occur in RDD1.

Basically i want to generate unique ID (key) for each row in RDD2 , such that this unique ID does not occur in RDD1.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

1000000000007765 | x,y

1000000000001190 | s,c,f

1000000000023467 | q,r,t,z,l

**CODE UPDATE:**

```
JavaPairRDD<String,String> RDD1 = sc.textFile(args[0]).mapToPair(x->{
        String[] tokens = x.split(",");
        return new Tuple2<String,String>(tokens[0],tokens[1]); // here tokens[0] is key and tokens[1] is my data
    }).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK());
// RDD2 generated here
JavaPairRDD<String, String> RDD2_ZippedwithUniqueID =RDD2.zipWithUniqueId().mapToPair(x -> {
        String key = generateKey(x._2(), "1", 16); // method i am using to generate 16 digit fixed ID beginning with "1"
        return new Tuple2<String, String>(key, x._1);
    }).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK());
```

Now how to make sure , the keys that i have generated in rdd "RDD2_ZippedwithUniqueID" does not occur in RDD1.  I have used same method for generating keys in RDD1 previously( i.e using zipwithUniqueID and generateKey method)

```
JavaPairRDD<String,String> finalOutput = RDD1.union(RDD2_ZippedwithUniqueID);
```

Because while doing union of "RDD1" and ""RDD2_ZippedwithUniqueID" , i want to make sure that all the keys are unique.

RDD1 has around 125 million rows , while RDD2 has 5000 rows.

Comment: please share your actual input data, expected output and code tried.

Comment: I also tried by broadcasting keys of RDD1, and while assigning unique ids to RDD2 , checking if it exists in broadcasted keys . But it didnt work, since RDD1 has around 125 million rows i.e 125 million unique ids. RDD1 being large dataset, my code didnt worked. Also RDD1 will keep getting incremental updates, So broadcast does not look like scalable solution.

Comment: you can find your answers in these two questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189266/how-to-generate-unique-id-for-each-record-spark and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705038/how-do-i-add-an-persistent-column-of-row-ids-to-spark-dataframe